# How to sum values across different rows and summarise as one row (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have employee payments data that comes out as one row = one payment record. The variables describe the name, what payment it was and the value.

My end goal is to have a data frame in which each employee = one row with the different types of payments summed up and each payment type has its own variable.

Please see example:

```
data <- data.frame("name" = c("John", "John", "John", "Marie", "Marie", "Alex"),
               "payment.reason" = c("bonus", "bonus", "commission", "commission", "commission", "discretionary bonus"),
               "value" = c(1000, 5000, 2500, 1500, 500, 2500))
```

which looks like this:

```
   name      payment.reason value
1  John               bonus  1000
2  John               bonus  5000
3  John          commission  2500
4 Marie          commission  1500
5 Marie          commission   500
6  Alex discretionary bonus  2500
```

and this is the end result I am after:

```
goal
   name bonus commission discretionary.bonus
1  John  6000       2500                   0
2 Marie     0       2000                   0
3  Alex     0          0                2500
```

I know I'll need to spread the data to push the payment.reason values into columns, but I am struggling to figure out how to sum each individual payment type value for each person and have the data come out grouped by each person.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

We can do all of this with `pivot_wider` in `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(data, name, names_from = payment.reason, values_from = value, values_fn = list(value = sum))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name  bonus commission `discretionary bonus`
#>   <fct> <dbl>      <dbl>                 <dbl>
#> 1 John   6000       2500                    NA
#> 2 Marie    NA       2000                    NA
#> 3 Alex     NA         NA                  2500
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note (as in @AlexB's answer) that you can also add `values_fill = list(value = 0)` if you need explicit `0`s instead of `NA`.

Comment: Nice use of `values_fn`

Comment: Thank you - one line solution - really elegant!

Answer (score 5):

```
library(tidyr)    
data %>%
  group_by(name, payment.reason) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = payment.reason,  values_from = value, values_fill = list(value = 0))

  name  `discretionary bonus` bonus commission
  <fct>                 <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Alex                   2500     0          0
2 John                      0  6000       2500
3 Marie                     0     0       2000
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` and make use of the `fun.aggregate`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), name ~ payment.reason, value.var = 'value', sum)
#    name bonus commission discretionary bonus
#1:  Alex     0          0                2500
#2:  John  6000       2500                   0
#3: Marie     0       2000                   0
```

---

Or `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(value ~ name + payment.reason, data)
#    payment.reason
#name    bonus commission discretionary bonus
#  Alex      0          0                2500
#  John   6000       2500                   0
#  Marie     0       2000                   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, value := sum(value), by = c("name", "payment.reason")]
data <- unique(data)
data <- reshape(data, idvar = "name", timevar = "payment.reason", direction = "wide")
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
colnames(data) = gsub("value.", "", colnames(data))
data

         name       bonus       commission        discretionary bonus
  #  1:  John        6000             2500                         0
  #  2: Marie           0             2000                         0
  #  3:  Alex           0                0                      2500
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution, where `reshape()` and `aggregate()` are used

```
dfout <- reshape(aggregate(data[3],data[-3],FUN = sum),
                 direction = "wide",
                 idvar = "name",
                 timevar = "payment.reason")
dfout[is.na(dfout)] <- 0
```

such that

```
> dfout
   name value.bonus value.commission value.discretionary bonus
1  John        6000             2500                         0
3 Marie           0             2000                         0
4  Alex           0                0                      2500
```